# Bootstrap Popover - Close on click anywhere

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just wondering if this is a good way to do it or if I'm being stupid. Basically any click in body is verified to not be the popover anchor, or within the popover. If it's not, then it hides all popovers.

```
$("body").on('click', function(e) {
if(!$(event.target).hasClass('with-popover') && !$(event.target).parents('.with-popover').length && !$(event.target).parents('.popover').length){
$(".with-popover").popover('hide');
};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this stupid? no. Just a few modifications to make it a little more efficient.

```
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target); // One jQuery object instead of 3

    // Compare length with an integer rather than with negation
    if ( ! target.hasClass('with-popover') 
         && target.parent('.with-popover').length === 0
         && target.parent('.popover').length === 0) {

         $('.with-popover').popover('hide');
    }
});
```

jQuery also provides a `size()` function that also just returns the length. I never use it anymore but just to be aware.

I was unsure what the `return true` was doing and the final `});` maybe you had this wrapped in a function.

Comment: Oh yep, I had it in a $(function(){ and the return true; was a debug thing I should have removed. OH lol...and the return true; was supposed to be within the on click...jeez. BTW, I like the object caching. Forgot to do that. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: No problem at all :-)

Comment: Just so anyone else that sees this knows, you must use .parents or it will only check the immediate parent.